how to solve this?email validation using javascript?
var a=document.getElementById("email").value;
var check=/[A-za-z]{3}@gmail.com\b/i;
console.log(check.test(a),"true",a,check)
if(check.test(a)==true)
{
    alert("correct")
}
else if(check.test(a)==false){
    alert('false')
}

The program currently provides correct validation for email addresses in the format hhhh.ggggh@gmail.com and hhhh.ggh@gmail.com. However, it returns false for the input hhhh.gh@gmail.com. The desired adjustment is to exclusively validate and accept the format hhhh.ggh@gmail.com while maintaining the current

Email validation is notoriously difficult to get right which is why many forms ask you to enter the email twice in two different fields, and then check to see if they correlate.

Does this answer your question? How can I validate an email address in JavaScript?

Your validation code doesn't work because email validation is quite difficult, and many edge cases must be covered.
You should use the regular expression below, which is the RFC 5322 Official Standard:
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

(js version)
Source: https://emailregex.com/
Here is example code:
function validateEmail(input) {
    var regexpr = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    if (input.value.match(regexpr)) {
        console.log("Valid email address");
        return true
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid email address");
        return false;
    }
}


Here you have two REGEX approaches that state they follow RFC2822 Email Validation standards.
https://regex101.com/r/DPiLbv/1
https://regexr.com/2rhq7
You could use some lists of e-mails to test it, as was asked here:
list of email addresses that can be used to test a javascript validation script
